# Git Bash does not work for npm, node, ng commands but all these commands works in powershell windows 10

Tags: node.js, bash, git, npm

Few months back all worked well but now some update or something broke my setup for Angular development setup. 
I got all latest node, npm, ts, ng and VS code. Used to work well. 
But today, after few months i updated all and found that these commands for ng doesnot work in Git BASH MING64 command window. 
All works well and in windows cmd and powershell. 
I noticed strange forward and backward slashes in path under git Bash window though.
My environment path for System and current user all set.

```
RonPC@RON-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents/VScode-Projects/AngularProjects/angular2020/jan2020 (master)
$ ng --version
C:\Users\RonPC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

RonPC@RON-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents/VScode-Projects/AngularProjects/angular2020/jan2020 (master)
$ npm ng --version
C:\Users\RonPC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

RonPC@RON-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents/VScode-Projects/AngularProjects/angular2020/jan2020 (master)
$ npx ng --version
C:\Users\RonPC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

RonPC@RON-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents/VScode-Projects/AngularProjects/angular2020/jan2020 (master)
$ node v
C:\Users\RonPC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

RonPC@RON-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents/VScode-Projects/AngularProjects/angular2020/jan2020 (master)
$ node --version
C:\Users\RonPC\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found

RonPC@RON-DESKTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents/VScode-Projects/AngularProjects/angular2020/jan2020 (master)
```

anyone got tip to get it fixed. I tried installing git BASH again but no help.
regards

[Screenshot of path for system environment vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOobT.png)

[Screenshot showing my installed components of node, npm and ng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E8q4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

After going through numerous solution listed on different forums, re-installing Nodejs/Git Bash cmd, tinkering PATHS.. no luck.

Very simple solution:

But i uninstalled "node" from Add Remove Programme --> deleted folder"npm" & "npm-cache" from location  --> C:\Users\RonPC\AppData\Roaming

Reinstalled Node.js(npm installed with it) and it worked like charm.

Hopefully it saves anyone having trouble for this reason.

Regards

Comment: Just a note, you should add `npm install -g @angular/cli` to get access to `ng`